# Appending lists using multiprocessing pool

Tags: python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I am new to python, and the multiprocessing module. I created a far simplified version of what I am trying to accomplish to distill my problem. The issue is that the variables don't seem to update when called outside of the function where they are appended/the worker processes .

After researching I thought it might have something to do with queues? However, I believe *queues* to be more about sharing memory between the processes which I don't believe is required in my situation, since each list could be appended independently.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def build(array):
    array.append("hello")
    return array


if __name__== '__main__':
    x=["yo","sup"]
    y=["blah", "blah"]
    z=["apple","banana"]
    w=["cats", "dogs"]

    p=Pool(4)
    p.map(build,[x,y,z,w])
    p.close()
    p.join()

    print x, y, z, w
```

When I run the code above, it simply returns x,y,z,w as imputed without appending "hello" to each list and I cannot figure out why. I know that if I put the print statement at the end of the function *build* that it will output the appended lists. I also realize that I could do the following:

```
results = p.map(build,[x,y,z,w])

print results
```

However, in my actual project I need to utilize x, y, z, w later and would prefer not to index *results* to get the list I am looking for. Is there anyway to have the changes made to the lists stick, so to speak, outside of the worker processes?

Answer (score 1):

Each **process has its own memory heap** so your lists are copied to the Process Pool workers memory and are changed **only** there